# Rails has_many relationships when not saved (possibly ajax related)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord, has-many, eager-loading

Have a quick question about the `has_many` and `belongs to`. I'm in a situation where a `:user has_many :accounts`, and an `:account belongs_to the user`.

In my controller, I first assign `@accounts = current_user.accounts`. Debugging [correctly] reports to me that this particular use has 2 accounts. In the next line, I save an invalid account (debugging also tells me correctly that it is invalid). However, when I inspect `current_user.accounts.count` versus `current_user.accounts.all.count` versus `current_user.accounts.all(order: 'created_at DESC')`, I get the following values:

```
- current_user.accounts.count = 2
 - current_user.accounts.all.count = 3
 - current_user.accounts.all(order: 'created_at DESC') = 2
```

Inspection of the database confirms that the invalid model indeed did not get saved.

Furthermore, in my dynamically ajax re-loaded view to which I feed `@accounts = current_user.accounts` (which is set after the if-else loop checking `if @account.save` worked), it loops through and displays 3 accounts, including the invalid account.

Here's the code for the controller:

```ruby
def create

    @account = current_user.accounts.new(account_params) 

    if @account.save
      @accounts = current_user.accounts.all(order: 'created_at DESC')
      #redirect_to accounts_path, :success => "Account successfully created."
      flash[:success] = "Account sucessfully created."
      # respond_to :js
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          render :create
        }
      end


    else
      @accounts = current_user.accounts.all(order: 'created_at DESC')

      flash[:error] = "There was a problem with adding your account."
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
          render :create
        }
      end

    end
    puts "Final Accounts is #{@accounts.count} compared to #{current_user.accounts.all.count} compared to #{current_user.accounts.count}" # outputs 2, 3, and 2 for an invalid model being saved
  end
```

Can someone explain to me the proper way I should be doing this? Or better yet, what is going on under the Rails engine? I feel sheepishly noob for having this issue.

How do I tell rails to only load the `current_user.accounts` that are saved in the db? Is this eager-loading related?

I'm running on Rails 4, with postgresql if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The reason of confusion is a [CollectionProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html)** in `ActiveRecord::Associations` (things are bit more complicated, than they looked):

`current_user.accounts` is a CollectionProxy, not an `Array`.

Think of CollectionProxy as of container, which internally has `@owner` as current_user, `@target` as set of accounts and `@reflection` - kinda links (associations) between `@owner` and `@target`

When you run `current_user.accounts.new()` - you just add another object into `@target`, so iterating over `current_user.accounts` you're iterating over @target, which contains objects including newly created.

**But wait, why does `.count` return less objects?**

Because Rails are lazy and `@target` is not loaded until you really need its objects(=accounts). So to just run `.count` it's cheaper to run direct SQL-request instead of instantiation of all objects in `@target` and then count 'em.

That's why when you do `current_user.accounts.count` you get amount of saved objects. And when you do `current_user.accounts.all.count` - it instantiate all objects in `@target`, convert 'em into `Array` and count accounts in this array (equal to `current_user.accounts.size`).

BTW, `all` is deprecated in Rails 4, use `to_a` instead

**So, what do I do with all this knowledge, man? I just need to show accounts without unsaved one.**

Just force reload: `@accounts = current_user.accounts(force_reload = true)`

OR `@accounts = current_user.accounts.reload`

OR `@accounts = current_user.accounts.order('created_at DESC')` It will run reload automagically because order needs direct request to objects via SQL

Comment: Thanks Leger. Can you explain why my view would be loading the unsaved invalid account model though? Without the '.all(order:'created_at DESC')'  part, my view when iterating through @accounts manages to also iterate on the invalid saved model.

Comment: UPDated answer for more details. In short - without the '.all(order:'created_at DESC')' part you're iterating with `.each` over Array created of accounts (because `.each` implies `to_a` before being applied).

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot Leger. I figured something like that was going on in the back, just wasn't sure what to do with it or what specifically it was. Thanks for the help!